# Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Context was expected -(notification channel in kotlin-class specific error)

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-context, android-workmanager

I am making an app which requires the use of work manager to make a notification, I know how to make notifications in an activity but writing them in a separate kotlin file in the `do work` method as follows:

```
class NotificationWorkManager(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters):
    Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

    //notification variables
    val CHANNEL_ID = "channel_ID"
    val CHANNEL_NAME = "channel_NAME"
    val NOTIFICATION_ID = 0

    override fun doWork(): Result {


        triggerNotify()
        return Result.success()
    }

    fun triggerNotify(){
        createNotificationChannel()
        //big picture:notification
        val notiStyle = NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
        var remote_picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(applicationContext.resources, R.drawable.make_new)
        notiStyle.bigPicture(remote_picture)

//open the app from outside the app
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(applicationContext).run{
                addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
                getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            }
    
//main notification variable
            val notification= NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Workmg")
                .setContentText("basdasdadfhgafgsgsfg")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_bb)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setStyle(notiStyle)
                .setProgress(100,10,true)//true keeps scroller running
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(applicationContext.resources, R.drawable.make_new))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build()
    
            val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification)
        }

    
        fun createNotificationChannel(){
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                val channel= NotificationChannel( CHANNEL_ID,CHANNEL_NAME,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH).apply {
                    lightColor= Color.RED
                    enableLights(true)
                }
                val manager= getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            }
        }
    }
```

My error arises in the last few lines where the `manager` variable is declared along with a red-wavy line underneath `NOTIFICATION_SERVICE` ::

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Context was expected
```

This does not happen if the code is written directly in the `Main Activity` which i am not doing in this case becuase iI want to use it in a `Work Manager`.

I tried using Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE but still got the same error.

Please help...

Comment: Does the `import` statement of the `NOTIFICATION_SERVICE` is successfully included?

Comment: Yes, like this: import android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To acquire a system service, we generally need both `Context` object and some kind of a service identifier (e.g. `String`). When we acquire a system service from `Activity` (or e.g. `Service`) we only need to provide an identifier, as `Activity` is itself a `Context` object, so `Context` is already known. In such a case we use [Context.getSystemService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSystemService(java.lang.String)) function.

In your case you are outside of the `Context`, so I'm not sure what is the `getSystemService()` function you use. Maybe you imported a static function: [ContextCompat.getSystemService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#getSystemService(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)). In that case, as you can see in the documentation, you need to provide both `Context` and service identifier to it.

But anyway, workers have access to the context using `applicationContext` property, so you should be able to acquire a system service with

```kotlin
val manager= applicationContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
```