# Android with Kotlin, can't get the BluetoothAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetoothadapter

I follow the instructions in https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/setup , trying to setup Bluetooth. When I am trying to get the BluetoothAdapter,

```
val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager? = 
getSystemService(BluetoothManager::class.java)
val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = bluetoothManager?.getAdapter()
if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
    // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
}
```

I get the error

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Class<BluetoothManager> but Context was expected
```

How can I work it around. Anyone?

Comment: Is that code part of a Context? Or just it by itself in an otherwise empty file?

Comment: @AlexT It is inside a composable, in a screen that is suposed to facilitate a BLE connection. A NavController parameter in the composable. fun BluetoothScanScreen(navController:NavController){ ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the getSystemService incorrectly

It must be done like this:

```
val bluetoothManager = context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
```

Then you can get the adapter like this:

```
val adapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
```

Comment: I get  "Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Context was expected" for    "val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager"

Comment: It worked when used Context.getSystemService() as specified here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69460500/kotlin-type-mismatch-inferred-type-is-string-but-context-was-expected-notifi

Comment: Correct. You need to also use context. I just though due to seeing your code that you were in a with(context) or something

Answer (score 0):

I followed Tom Truyen suggestion and troubleshooted a newly arisen malfunction according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69460500/kotlin-type-mismatch-inferred-type-is-string-but-context-was-expected-notifi) , and it worked as follows

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val bluetoothManager = context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
val bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
```